# How can I get items from a List element for dropdown menu for Spring forms?

Tags: spring, forms, drop-down-menu

I want to use a ***list element*** for ***drop-down select menu*** but it implemented everywhere with model. I use Spring I want the user to select items from a ***static list***.
There are some use like

```
<form:select path="...." items=$(......)>
```

but it needs a ***model*** for items as I understood. Also I don't want to post anything I just need the value of the ***select menu*** and I will do everything with ***JS***. How can I achieve this?
My List element:

```
private static String[] lang = {"en","fr","tr","es","de"};
```

I tried to use List like that but didn't work. I mean every form elements gone.

```
 <form:form  commandName="TranslateService">
     <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
         <label class="control-label" for="first-name">Target Languages<span class="required">*</span>
         </label>
         <div>
             <form:select path="lang" items="${lang}"></form:select>
         </div>
     </div>     

</form:form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's a hard way to solve your question. instead of this you can create a model for form.

Comment: You're right bro I did it like that and problem solved. Thanks anyway